# Допустимое количество правок

Tags: поддержка

Возникла проблема - не могу делать новые правки, пока текущие не будут утверждены. Какой лимит стоит для ожидающих правок и сколько тербуется времени людям с более высоким рейтингом, чтобы их утвердить (в среднем, разумеется, понимаю, что иногда людей мало)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не стоит делать правки следующих видов:

- минорные (типа удаления приветствий или исправления небольших орфографических/пунктуационных) - сейчас принял, но вообще-то мог и отклонить - чтобы делать такие правки надо подождать достаточной репутации, чтобы они не попадали в очередь проверок.
- полностью переписывающие вопрос - оставил на усмотрение автора - вроде бы и стало лучше, но как-то уж слижком сильно всё переписано
- удаляющие мнение автора по поводу проблемы - отклонил, естественно

---

Вообще, есть несколько лимитов на предлагаемые правки:

- общее число правок пользователя - зависит от пользователя и его истории правок
- общее число правок в очереди проверок - нельзя, чтобы очередь росла и долго висели вопросы с непросмотренными правками
- [число ожидающих правок от конкретного пользователя: 5](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/309650)

Подробнее об ограничениях [есть на metaSE](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/309650).

Comment: 5 pending правок максимум.

Comment: @Suvitruf, да - нашёл ссылку.

Comment: _> чтобы они не попадали в очередь проверок_ - что ж в этом такого ужасного? мы же не enSO, эта очередь у нас всё равно пуста, и мне не жалко попроверять даже минорные правки

Comment: tl;dr где-то потерялся.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. По поводу несущественных правок - я просто проводил небольшой эксперимент, больше так не буду. А если честно, то немного коробит даже одна орфографическая ошибка/опечатка или отсутствие запятой, поскольку сам Я работаю с естственным языком и компьютерной лингвистикой и в некоторой степени перфекционист;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а когда участник имеет требуемую репутацию и производит правки, не попадающие в очередь проверок - он получает за это +2 балла репутации?

Comment: @Jenssen, нет. +2 дают только за проверяемые правки. И то там, вроде, верхний лимит есть, есколько всего могут дать.

Answer (score 4):

Докину обратной связи по правкам.

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/208748. Тут в вопросе некорретное условие задачи. Стилистические правки ему не помогут. Нужно, чтобы автор сам написал, что же он имеет в виду.

  Если бы условие задачи было корректным, то следовало бы как минимум убрать дублированные в заголовке метки и целиком переписать заголовок, потому что сейчас он слишком обобщенный.
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/208715. Хорошо, что вы переформулировали заголовок. Плохо, что так и не ясно, что за такая «непонятная ошибка» случилась у автора. У любой подобной ошибки есть текстовое сообщение. У многих есть ещё и код ошибки. Тут нужно было добиваться от автора, чтобы он написал точное сообщение, а потом вынести это сообщение в заголовок ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=stack%20overflow)).